# Java uses or overrides a deprecated API. Native screen shot & fluttershare

Tags: android, flutter

Im having these error when i compile apk of my flutter app. What could be the workaround for this?

Note: C:\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\native_screenshot-1.0.0\android\src\main\java\jpg\ivan\native_screenshot\NativeScreenshotPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_share-2.0.0\android\src\main\java\com\example\fluttershare\FlutterSharePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Tried:
flutter pub clean
flutter pub upgrade
flutter pub get
flutter pub run

but still having  those errors.

Comment: those are not errors, they are just warnings, the app should work just fine

Comment: i figured out that the error on why it was not building was due to missing drawables.